# How to replace the gone 60 free controls by DevExpress?

Tags: winforms, dll, controls, devexpress

I had an [open-source spare-time project](http://replayer.codeplex.com/) two years ago where I used the free 60 controls by DevExpress, from the link here: https://www.devexpress.com/Products/Free/NetOffer/

I was vey happy with these and I even personally [recommended these controls here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2019411/79485).

My project now is quite old, but now I want to make some minor changes, and I just experienced, to my surprise, that I will no longer be able to build it, because I took a dependency on those controls. I did not copy these DevXpress libraries locally, so I really lost them.

**What can I do about these now missing controls?** Does anybody faced the same already? Should I replace them (quite a lot of work, because I do not want to change the UI at all now), or does someone still have these around?

Comment: If those controls were free they must still be available somewhere in cyberspace... did you try searching by exact dll name?

Comment: @Dean K. Yeah, in my project of course... Too stupid a question of mine! Gonna answer it now myself...

Comment: Have you checked your DevExpress account, there you can get that download from `My Products` menu link.

Comment: @NiranjanKala Although I see some of the products that I downloaded earlier, I can not find that 60 free controls package in the list. Can you?

Comment: Yes, i have that download in my product list and i have registered those controls with my email id while registering..

Comment: @NiranjanKala Too bad i did'nt register them. However, my personal problem is solved by my own answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My mind just had a glitch :-/ These DLL's are of course found in my installer package. I just installed my own software from [codeplex](http://replayer.codeplex.com/), where I published it, searched thru the Harddisk and voilà, here the are, listed:

```
DevExpress.Data.v10.2.cdf-ms
DevExpress.Data.v10.2.dll
DevExpress.Data.v10.2.manifest
DevExpress.Utils.v10.2.cdf-ms
DevExpress.Utils.v10.2.dll
DevExpress.Utils.v10.2.manifest
DevExpress.XtraBars.v10.2.cdf-ms
DevExpress.XtraBars.v10.2.dll
DevExpress.XtraBars.v10.2.manifest
DevExpress.XtraEditors.v10.2.cdf-ms
DevExpress.XtraEditors.v10.2.dll
DevExpress.XtraEditors.v10.2.manifest
DevExpress.XtraTreeList.v10.2.cdf-ms
DevExpress.XtraTreeList.v10.2.dll
DevExpress.XtraTreeList.v10.2.manifest
DevExpress.XtraVerticalGrid.v10.2.cdf-ms
DevExpress.XtraVerticalGrid.v10.2.dll
DevExpress.XtraVerticalGrid.v10.2.manifest
```

So, just in case, anyone needs those DLL's (The original 60 controls suite consisted of more files, however), you can get them the same way from my installer.

I would guess this is legal, since distribution in my project (with LGPL v2) was also legal.

Comment: can you  upload these dlls somewhere so i can download. i really need them

Comment: I have added these libraries in the lib section of my project's source code. [Browse or download the source from here](http://replayer.codeplex.com/SourceControl/BrowseLatest) The libraries can be found in the `Replayer.WinForms.Ui/lib` subfolder

Comment: yes i browsed the libs, but its not all the 60 controls. any idea where i could get those?

Comment: Just a note you could also have logged into your devexpress account and got the original installer package.  This of course can not be redistributed.  (Also they have continued to update them)

Comment: @marcel if you have the installer for the free controls, can you please share byt uploading to onedrive or googledrive?

Comment: @Smith and anyone else looking for the original installer. I unfortunately do not have it at hand anymore. Otherwise I would not have asked the question in the first place. All I can offer, is the redistribution of the mentioned DLLs from within my project's public source repo, alread linked to in my comment above: http://replayer.codeplex.com/SourceControl/BrowseLatest

Comment: @Marcel Yes i see them, but it only has about 5 controls, not the 60, or you could search your hardrive and upload all the DLLs instead?

Answer (score 3):

latest free control is version 11.2 you can download it from [github](https://github.com/danieljeffrey111/HydroDesktop/tree/master/Binaries/Application%20Extensions)

Comment: Link to github is broken.